# Two Limits involving an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Let $$I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}-x^{n+p-1}}{(1+x^{n})(1+x^{n+p})} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$ where $p$ is a positive natural number.
> Show that:
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 I_n=p\ln{2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} \left({\frac{n^2I_n}{p\ln{2}}}\right)^n=e^{-p} $$

For the first one I substituted $t=x^n$ and we get:

$$ n^2I_n=n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{\frac{p}{n}}}{(1+x)(1+x^{1+\frac{p}{n}})} \, \mathrm{d}x .$$

Now I argue that $ x^{1+\frac{p}{n}} $ converges uniformly to $x$ on $[0,1]$ so we can substitute it with $x$ and in the limit they will be equal. I do have a rigorous proof for than using the definition for uniform convergence and then making an inequality involving $I_n$, but its just too long for this post and I am also not sure its correct. So please tell me if such argument is possible.

In the end we have:

$$ n^2I_n = n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{\frac{p}{n}}}{(1+x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Now $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is the diff power series $\sum_{k\ge0} x^k$, hence after multiplying by $1-x^{\frac{p}{n}}$ and integrating we get:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}p\sum_{k\ge1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+\frac{p}{n}}$$

and by the Weierstrass M-test, using the alternating harmonic series as for $M_n$, we get that the limit is equal to $p\ln{2}$

If I try the same trick for the second limit (writing the integral as a series) I get a different result, namely $e^{\frac{-p\pi^2}{12\ln{2}}}$... It has to do with my shady argument above, that maybe works only for the first limit.

Please help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We get

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n} - \frac{x^{n+p-1}}{1+x^{n+p}} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{n}\log(1+x^n) - \frac{1}{n+p}\log(1 + x^{n+p}) \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= \frac{p}{n(n+p)}\log 2.
\end{align*}

This immediately proves that $n^2 I_n \to p \log 2$. Moreover,

$$ \left( \frac{n^2 I_n}{p \log 2} \right)^n = \frac{1}{(1+p/n)^n} \to \frac{1}{e^p} = e^{-p}. $$

Comment: Thank you! So dissapointed I didnt see that